# Close cmd while Tk object remains

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, visible

So I made a simple calculator in Python 3.7 and made a batch file to get it to run from the CMD. The thing is, after I run the batch file, I get a CMD window and then the Tk window, but the CMD window remains there and shuts my program down if I close it.
Is there a way to hide the CMD window or just omit its apperance at all?

Here is how it looks, in case my description is bad:
[image: Cmd window visible and active]

The BATCH FILE reads:

```
Start "" "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\draft.py"
```

Comment: Mind showing that batch file too?

Comment: Its nothing special, just this: Start "" "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\draft2.pyw"

Comment: Please add the batch file in your question by [edit]ing your post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pythonw` executable, or rename your script to something`.pyw`.

`.pyw` is a special extension for Python files on Windows which are associated with `pythonw`, the Python interpreter that does not pop up the console window at all.

Comment: @Akenaten, take a look at this to learn how to say thanks on SO: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)